# Slidify - Slidy Framework - should it work?

Tags: slidify

This is my first day trying to use slidify.

Just wondering if the slidy option for framework should work?
I am able to generate slides using each of the other options in brackets  {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides} however with slidy as the option, the index.html generated file has a size of 0.

```
---
title       : Testing
framework   : slidy        # {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides, ...}
highlighter : highlight.js  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
hitheme     : tomorrow      # 
widgets     : []            # {mathjax, quiz, bootstrap}
mode        : selfcontained # {standalone, draft}
---
```

(I am using an extract of the R markdown code linked to from: http://lamages.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/interactive-presentation-with-slidify.html)

Comment: Did you install a slidy framework? I only see these 4 (io2012, deck.js, shower, landslide) enumerated on the main [Slidify](http://slidify.org/) page.

Comment: The `slidy` framework is included in the `dev` branch of `slidifyLibraries`. To use it, you will also have to update to the `dev` branch of `slidify`.

Comment: I thought I had installed from the dev branch; using:install_github("slidify", "ramnathv", ref="dev")
install_github("slidifyLibraries", "ramnathv", ref="dev")  My versions are as follows: slidify 0.3.52 and slidifyLibraries 0.3.1

Comment: I just checked and realized that I had not updated `slidy` for the latest versions of the packages. I have added this to my to-do list and will update soon.